# Prolog Find Minimum numbers from 2 lists

Tags: prolog, minimum

I am trying to find 2 minimum numbers from two lists. I can find from one list, but what if the second minimum number is in the second list.

For example, `min_in_list([2,8,7], [5,3,4], M)` should `M = [2, 3]`.

Code below is for one list.

```
min_in_list([Min],Min).                 % We've found the minimum

min_in_list([H,K|T],M) :-
    H =< K,                             % H is less than or equal to K
    min_in_list([H|T],M).               % so use H

min_in_list([H,K|T],M) :-
    H > K,                              % H is greater than K
    min_in_list([K|T],M).               % so use K
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to have two minimum variables, then iterate through the lists and compare to both, replacing the values when appropriate. I'm not a prolog guy, so I can't help with the coding.

Comment: If your `min_in_list` works for one list, then you could use it twice: `min_in_list(L1, L2, [M1, M2]) :- min_in_list(L1, M1), min_in_list(L2, M2).` It seems like an odd predicate, though, that would have hard-coded arguments to independently get the minimums of two different lists, unless there's some other relationship between the lists that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from finding the minimum for each list separately?

Answer (score 0):

*Decomposition* is your friend here. So is thinking *generically*. Finding the minimum value in each of two lists is really no different than finding the minimum value in any number of lists. The solution shouldn't be any more complex than this:

```
min_in_list( Xs , Ys , Ms ) :- minimums( [Xs,Ys] , Ms ) .

minimums( []     , [] ) .
minimums( [L|Ls] , [M|Ms] ) :- minimum(L,M) , minimums(Ls,Ms).

minimum( [X|Xs] , M ) :- minimum(Xs,X,M) .

minimum( []     , M , M ) .
minimum( [X|Xs] , T , M ) :- X <  T , minimum(Xs,X,M).
minimum( [X|Xs] , T , M ) :- X >= T , minimum(Xs,T,M).
```